# Usando TIdHttp e TIdConnectionIntercept criados em runtime

Tags: delphi, thread, multithreading, indy-10

tenho um método que faz uma conexão com um servidor RestFUL e para isso usa os componentes TIdHttp, TIdConnectionIntercept e outros criados em runtime, até ai tudo bem, o problema é que eu preciso obter o retorno do evento "OnReceive" do componente TIdConnectionIntercept e não sei como fazer isso, veja o código:

```
procedure ConHttpThread;
    var
     IdHTTPLibSysLoc : TIdHTTP;
     IdCookieManagerLibSysLoc : TIdCookieManager;
     IdConnectionInterceptLibSysLoc : TIdConnectionIntercept;
     AuthSSL : TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
     IdLogDebug1Loc : TIdLogDebug;
     sHtmlResp, sHtmlErro : String;
   begin
    AuthSSL := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);
    IdLogDebug1Loc := TIdLogDebug.Create(nil);
    IdCookieManagerLibSysLoc := TIdCookieManager.Create(nil);
    IdConnectionInterceptLibSysLoc := TIdConnectionIntercept.Create;
    IdConnectionInterceptLibSysLoc.Intercept := IdLogDebug1Loc;
    IdConnectionInterceptLibSysLoc.OnReceive := IdConnectionInterceptLibSysLocReceive;
    IdHTTPLibSysLoc := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);

    try
      sHtmlResp := IdHTTPLibSysLoc.Post(xUrlPost, paramsLog);
    except
      sHtmlErro := ''; //variável s do evento IdConnectionInterceptLibSysLocReceive
    end;
    IdHTTPLibSysLoc.Disconnect;
   end;
```

Evento do componente

```
procedure TFPrin.IdConnectionInterceptLibSysLocReceive(
  ASender: TIdConnectionIntercept; var ABuffer: TIdBytes);
var
  i: Integer;
  s: String;
begin
  s := '';
  for i := Low(ABuffer) to High(ABuffer) do
    s := s + UTF8Encode(chr(ABuffer[i]));
end;
```

O evento é chamado quando faz o TidHttp.Post(), e quando o servidor retorna um erro ele vai direto para o Except, não posso utilizar uma variável glogal pois esse método principal é mult thread, alguma ideia de como pegar o retorno depois do Post?

Obrigado!

Comment: por que em vez de usar variável global, não faz uma classe responsável por esse processo e crie a variável nessa sua classe?

Comment: Experimente retirar o "nil" "IdHTTPLibSysLoc := TIdHTTP.Create;"  e finalizar com "IdHTTPLibSysLoc.Free;", já que desconectou.